# Richedit style formatting changes on its own

Tags: delphi, styles, richedit

(Someone edit the title if you can understand and define my problem better.)

The problem which I am having is with style formatting of a RichEdit "reverting" back to the default "nothing" aka `[]` and then back to whatever I set it to, bold or italic for example.

The thing that is at fault - I assume, since I have no idea how it is breaking things - is a procedure (REMainLinesCheck) that checks for amount of lines in the RichEdit and deletes the first one until a certain point is reached (to show a maximum of 14 lines at once) like so:

```
while REMain.Lines.Count > 14 do
  REMain.Lines.Delete(0);
```

I have 6 occurrences of the above procedure in other procedures that add lines to the RichEdit, but none of them change `RichEdit.SelAttributes.Style` but one, which was adding only one Bold line like so:

```
REMain.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
REMain.Lines.Add('something');
REMainLinesCheck;
```

So I have removed all occurrences except that one and started poking around, it didn't take long to see that it was working in fact fine, regular and bold lines where being added normally and excess lines where being deleted - no problems. But as soon as I reintroduced REMainLinesCheck procedure into another procedure (for clarity purposes, lets call it Proc3Lines, because that's what it does: adds 3 lines and then calls the check for excess lines), every line that follows this Proc3Lines that should be Bold is not... From what I have experienced here it seems that REMainLinesCheck does something in Proc3Lines, since without it everything is fine.

Obviously it's not a circle of procedures that call each other, but the other parts of the code have nothing to do with this RichEdit, not to mention that I don't change `RichEdit.SelAttributes.Style` anywhere for REMain except that one place that I have shown, there is another RichEdit in the same unit that I do change its line's style like that, but that cannot possibly be related in any way... could it? (No it does not, I just checked.)

Basically: what the hell Delphi? It cannot get any simpler than this and I am still managing to fail, can someone explain and/or fix this? Ask questions, I'll elaborate as much as I can if something is not clear.

Comment: The `RichEdit.SelAttributes.Style` is not persistent. It's being reset when you change the selection, what happens e.g. even when you add a line.

Comment: Implement [this code](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2003/a/bltip1203_5.htm)... check what is happening behind.. you will better understand... (you break the style removing.. start of style and not the end...)

Comment: When you do a selection to apply a style.. be sure that your selection starts **and** finishs on the **same** line.. if you need it on several lines... do it several times, for each lines, or do not remove the first lines to tail your RTE

Comment: @TLama, I didn't know that - exactly in those words, but I knew you loose the style after you set the line (the next line will be style-less) and I rely on that. It shouldn't affect my code (I think), because I set the Bold as the style every single time before adding the line. The problem is that text `"something"` from `REMain.Lines.Add('something');` is not Bold (when it follows a procedure that has `REMainLinesCheck` in it, without the said check it works fine and is Bold), when I explicitly just set it to be. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TLama, I see, I am doing that in another place, however somehow setting the style first and then adding a line without selecting it worked... well, does work, except in the situation I am having now. It's probably weirder that it worked for me normally up till now, than that it's not working in the given situation... I will change the code and will report back tomorrow.

Comment: @TLama, I think I fixed it, probably in a simpler way, too bad you have deleted your suggested answer as i did not copy it even though I wanted to see how it works (since I have no idea how to use `Perform`, I think that was what you used, right?). I'll add an answer shortly. Maybe you could take a look and see if your solution does the same but maybe better or something? And if so re-add your previous solution or just edit my asnwer to include an alternative?

Comment: @Whiler, what happens when my selection stretches over a few lines at once? I think after poking some more I have an answer to that - it propagates to the whole RichEdit or all the lines that follow? I am seeing the effects but I dont really understand, if `RichEdit.SelAttributes.Style` is not persistent as TLama pointed out, why is it doing that? As for as I understand, it's "scope" should end with the selection or whenever the selection is changed. However I am observing something opposite.

Comment: @Raith, undeleted for a while :-) About the `Perform` it's in fact `SendMessage` where you don't need to pass the handle to a target control. *What happens when my selection stretches over a few lines at once ?* Just nothing, it should be fine :-)

Comment: @TLama, it was not completely fine, the Bold style from that one procedure stayed as if it was set like so `REMain.Font.Style := [fsBold]`, and all lines that followed where bold. This still remains a mystery, as much as the original problem, I have a fix, rather a proper way to do it, but usually I want to understand why it's going on, especially when it's that consistent and reproducible.

Comment: That's just the behavior of the RichEdit control. If you open MS WordPad, type something, select it and apply a bold style for instance, then if you continue writing the following text will be bold. You need to go to the end of the line and unselect the bold style button to reset it. Moreover Delphi's `TRichEdit` when you add a new line add also the CRLF (or LF in new versions of Delphi) char at the end, what makes an extra line.

Comment: @TLama: I agree.. this should be fine.. but I raise a warning regarding the format behind... `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1036{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 Line\cf1 1\par
L\b ine\b0 2\par
Li\cf0 ne3\par
}`maybe a `\b` is not nicely closed...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To apply a format to a new added line, use the following:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LineIndex: Integer;
begin
  LineIndex := RichEdit1.Lines.Add('Something');
  RichEdit1.SelStart := RichEdit1.Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, LineIndex, 0);
  RichEdit1.SelLength := RichEdit1.Perform(EM_LINELENGTH, RichEdit1.SelStart, 0);
  RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
end;
```

Comment: I have never imagined you could grab the line index while setting it! Now I know, that one line made this worth it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! But I'm afraid I don't get your last comment. From your question as it's stated came to my mind you don't know how to set the format to a new added line, so I've just posted this as to be the temporary example. But to explain what's going on there, the `EM_LINEINDEX` get the index of the first char of the passed line index, what is here the `LineIndex` variable. That's for the selection start. Then you get the length of this line by sending the `EM_LINELENGTH` message passing the index of a character in the line whose length you need to get. That's all the selection needs.

Comment: I thought I was doing it correctly, but it appears that I was doing it wrong, this example explains it and now I understand. This also works as a solution for my problem so I accepted it. Take a look at my alternative answer, it's not as good as yours but it shows I get it a little. I am just now reading about `SendMessage`/ `Perform`, the last two parameters are not clear to me (especially with `EM_LINELENGTH`), but that's expected because from what I gather the extra parameters are defined by the message that you pass. I cant seem to find an exhaustive list regarding these messages though...

Comment: All the RichEdit control messages are [`listed here`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). About the parameters of the `Perform` or `SendMessage` function; it depends on the message you are sending, if you take a look e.g. on the [`EM_LINEINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, then you can see the `wParam` and `lParam` descriptions and the only thing you need to do is to understand what they mean and pass them to the same named parameters of the `SendMessage` or `Perform` function.

Comment: ohhh... I think I was browsing those pages today but somehow skipped them or didn't read as attentively as now, useful nonetheless, thank you

Comment: Just to add, instead of calling `RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];` you could do this instead: `RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style + [fsBold];` which will maintain whatever other styles such as italic, underline etc have been used without losing them. Of course that is only suitable if needed to keep any previous formatting though.

Comment: @Blobby, I know and I hope it's clear from the statement, this was originally just as a temporary post showing how to apply bold style for a new added line, it was not intended to be the answer ;-)

Comment: I know you know :) - just thought I would add in case @Raith was not aware ;)

Comment: @Blobby, thanks, top off my head i probably wouldnt give a correct answer if you asked me how to keep previous formatting, here in particular I want it to be new every single time. Most useful part here however is how to use `Perform`, as well as the fact that you need to select text first to apply style, I was using styles wrong this whole time it seems.

Comment: This solved my issue with rich edit reverting back to default. I found problems when attempting to set selection to end, format, add text. This worked most of the time, but I found that it was not reliable. The algorithm of setting the selection to the end, adding text, selecting the added text and then formatting seems to be much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

```
procedure TformStart.Proc;
var
endtxtpos: integer;
begin
  endtxtpos := Length(REMain.Text);
  REMain.Lines.Add('something');
  REMain.SelStart := endtxtpos-(REMain.Lines.Count-1);
  REMain.SelLength := Length('something');
  REMain.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
end;
```

But since I don't know any better, please criticize and suggest how I can do it better.