# Make the first 4 characters in a richedit line bold

Tags: delphi, richedit

How can I make the first 4 characters in a line I am going to add bold?
Example:

```
richedit1.Lines.Add('Test123');
```

I want `Test` to be bold but leave `123` normal.

Can someone help me?

Comment: while the question is not an exact duplicate, the first answer to this question will give you exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645033/richedit-style-formatting-changes-on-its-own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.AddFormattedText(const AText: string; AStyle: TFontStyles);
begin
  RichEdit1.SelStart := RichEdit1.GetTextLen;
  RichEdit1.SelLength := 0;
  RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := AStyle;
  RichEdit1.SelText := AText;
end;
```

```
AddFormattedText('Test', [fsBold]);
AddFormattedText('123'+sLineBreak, []);
```